# Scrapy XPath - Can't get text within span

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to reach the address information on a site. Here's an example of my code:

```
companytype_list = sel.xpath('''.//li[@class="type"]/p/text()''').extract()
headquarters_list = sel.xpath('''.//li[@class="vcard hq"]/p/span[3]/text()''').extract()
companysize_list = sel.xpath('''.//li[@class="company-size"]/p/text()''').extract()
```

And here's an example of how addresses are formatted on the site:

```
<li class="type">
    <h4>Type</h4>
    <p>
        Privately Held
    </p>
</li>
<li class="vcard hq">
    <h4>Headquarters</h4>
    <p class="adr" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span class="street-address" itemprop="streetAddress">Kornhamnstorg 49</span>
        <span class="street-address" itemprop="streetAddress"></span>
        <span class="locality" itemprop="addressLocality">Stockholm,</span>
        <abbr class="region" title="Stockholm" itemprop="addressRegion">Stockholm</abbr>
        <span class="postal-code" itemprop="postalCode">S-11127</span>
        <span class="country-name" itemprop="addressCountry">Sweden</span>
    </p>
</li>
<li class="company-size">
    <h4>Company Size</h4>
    <p>
        11-50 employees
    </p>
```

But when I run the scrapy script I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` for the address (vcard hq). I've tried to rewrite the code to get the data but it does not work. The rest of the spider works fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine. But I guess your xpath expressions failed on another page or html part.

The problem is the use of indexes (`span[3]`) in the headquarters_list xpath expression. Using indexes you heavily depend on:

**1. The total number of the span elements**

**2. On the exact order of the span elements**

In general the use of indexes tend to make xpath expressions more fragile and more likely to fail. Thus, **if possible, I would always avoid the use of indexes.** In your example you actually take the locality of the address info. The span element can also easily be referenced by its class name which makes your expression much more robust:

```
//li[@class="vcard hq"]/p/span[@class='locality']/text()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do the trick. E.g. I've tried `//span[@class='locality']/text()` and `//li[@class="vcard hq"]//text()` but I still get nothing. 

I guess this might actually not be an xpath problem but something else, cause with these xpath's I should get something right?!

Comment: ok, I see in your comment to winiex's answer that you mixed up urls. So my solution works for you, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my testing code according to your problem description:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.selector import Selector


html_text = """
<li class="type">
    <h4>Type</h4>
    <p>
        Privately Held
    </p>
</li>
<li class="vcard hq">
    <h4>Headquarters</h4>
    <p class="adr" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span class="street-address" itemprop="streetAddress">Kornhamnstorg 49</span>
        <span class="street-address" itemprop="streetAddress"></span>
        <span class="locality" itemprop="addressLocality">Stockholm,</span>
        <abbr class="region" title="Stockholm" itemprop="addressRegion">Stockholm</abbr>
        <span class="postal-code" itemprop="postalCode">S-11127</span>
        <span class="country-name" itemprop="addressCountry">Sweden</span>
    </p>
</li>
<li class="company-size">
    <h4>Company Size</h4>
    <p>
        11-50 employees
    </p>
"""


sel = Selector(text=html_text)

companytype_list = sel.xpath(
    '''.//li[@class="type"]/p/text()''').extract()
headquarters_list = sel.xpath(
    '''.//li[@class="vcard hq"]/p/span[3]/text()''').extract()
companysize_list = sel.xpath(
    '''.//li[@class="company-size"]/p/text()''').extract()
```

It doesn't raise any exception. So chances are there exist web pages with a different structure causing errors.

It's a good practice to not using index directly in xpath rules. dron22's answer gives an awesome explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And concerning pages with different structures I'm only working with this specific page so far. 

But it still does not work. I guess the conclusion is that it's not an xpath problem? Any ideas what it might be instead?

Comment: Could you give me the html string in which case raised these errors? That will help a lot. :)

Comment: Wow, just realised I tried the script on a different page than cited above. The one I was working on didn't have any address. So in essence you were right, it was a different structure causing the errors. Thanks a lot for the help, and sorry for a stupid question.